# About ostream of c++

Tags: c++, iterator, cout

```
map<string,int> m;
string str;
while (cin >> str){
    ++m[str];
}
map<string, int>::const_iterator iter = m.begin();

while (iter != m.end()){
    cout << iter->first << (iter++)->second << endl;
}
return 0;
```

above is the code,but compiler give me a error about invalid dereference,so I
change last line like that:

```
cout<<(iter++)->first<<iter->second<<endl;
```

and I got right answer,my question is what cout have done make me have to write like this,Is it read string from back to front?how does it implement?
or am I wrong other place?

Comment: The problem is that it's not defined in which order the parameters will be evaluated. Increment the `iter` outside the `cout` statement.

Comment: I'm slightly surprised by the compiler error and would need to see the actual error message, along with the **exact** source to match up line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an expression of the form `a << b`, `a` and `b` must both be evaluated, but the order they are evaluated is unspecified, which means any order is permitted (`a` first, `b` first, both concurrently somehow).

The same goes when multiple such expressions are chained, such as `a << b << c`.

Practically, overloaded operators are implemented as function calls.  For example

```
std::cout << iter->first << (iter++)->second;   // drop  << endl for simplicity of discussion
```

may be expanded to something like

```
operator<<(operator<<(std::cout << iter->first), (iter++)->second);
```

The order of evaluation of function arguments is also unspecified.   So the order of evaluating `operator<<(std::cout << iter->first)` and `(iter++)->second)` before passing them to the outermost call of `operator<<()`.

It just so happens with your compiler that `(iter++)->second)` is evaluated before `operator<<(std::cout << iter->first)`, even though you were expecting the opposite.

The solution is not to mix too many operations with side effects in one statement, because that is a good way to trip over such ordering concerns.   In your case, do the output, and increment `iter` in the next statement.

```
cout << iter->first << iter->second << endl;
++iter;
```

Answer (score 1):

The << operator can evaluate its operands in any order. In your case it probably evaluated (iter++)->second before iter->first.

You should put your iter++ at the next line.

Comment: Or use a normal `for` loop, or a [range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is that there are multiple ways in which this can be evaluated. The problem is that **each** `operator<<` can evaluate its left side before its right side or vice versa. And since you have three, there are quite a few variants possible.

Now you're trying to use `iter` twice, and also modify it, in one statement, without anything to *sequence* that. That makes it Undefined Behavior. Anything may happen.

Fix: use two statements. Statements are sequenced in the obvious order.